# Random variable within Manipulate: how to make it independent on other controls

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, evaluation, random

The code sample:

```
Manipulate[
e = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, sigma], n];
{a, e},
{{n, 3}, 1, 5, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{sigma, 1}, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{a, 0}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

The problem: how to make `a` to change without updating `e` given `n`

and `sigma` unchanged.

Difference with suggested [solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15110/how-to-generate-new-random-numbers-in-a-manipulate-only-on-demand): random vars depend on other controls (i.e. `n` and `sigma`) of `Manipulate` body.

Comment: A quick and dirty hack would be fixing the seed (`BlockRandom`).

Comment: @Szabolcs, is there some more flexible solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Body of `Manipulate` is wrapped by `Dynamic` and `Dynamic` doesn't know what's inside inner `Dynamics`, that's how we can screen `a` variable to not prompt the very outer `Dynamic` to evaluate:

```
Manipulate[
 e = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, sigma], n];
 {Dynamic@a, e}, 
 {{n, 3}, 1, 5, 1,   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{sigma, 1}, 1, 2,  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{a, 0}, 0, 10, 1,  Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just as a follow up, what if I want to use `a` and `e` in the same expression, say, `a` + `e`. How `Dynamic` wrapper can be used in this case?

Comment: @garej for full controll over evaluation I'd go with `DynamicModule` and manually written solution. But in this qase when you put `Dynamic[a + e]` it still works right, doesn't it?

Comment: right! Now I clearily see the point. Thank's for a tip.

Comment: @garej great :) good luck.

Comment: @Kuba A quick question. Why doesn't wrapping `e` in `Refresh` work here? `Refresh[e = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, sigma], n], TrackedSymbols :> {sigma, n}];`  I thought for sure this was an alternative but it does not work.

Comment: @Edmund The problem is there you have the body which is more or less: `Dynamic[Refresh[...]; {a, e}]` so when you change only `a` it will prompt the whole content of `Dynamic` to be recreated.

Comment: @Edmund here's an example with `Refresh` that may be considered useful: `Manipulate[
 Refresh[e = amp RandomVariate[ NormalDistribution[0, sigma], n], 
  TrackedSymbols :> {sigma, n}];
 {Dynamic@a, e}, {{n, 3}, 1, 5, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{sigma, 1}, 1, 2, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a, 0}, 0, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {amp, 0, 1}]`

Comment: @Kuba I don't get why your comment example with the addition of `amp` in the `Refresh` works and mine does not. I also see that your comment example will work without the `Dynamic` on `a`.  Also, my `Refresh` will work with a `Dynamic` on `a` ; but that makes the `Refresh` redundant since your question answer has it working with `Dynamic` but without `Refresh`.

Comment: @Edmund the difference is that `amp` isn't outside `Refresh` when `a` is.

Comment: @Kuba I have been thinking of `Refresh` as a gatekeeper to the code it contains. I my mind `e` should never ever update unless the `TrackedSymbols` condition has been met. That is how I have understood the concept of `Refresh`. However, this apparently is not the case as this rather simple (or so I thought) example has shown. Somewhere I've missed this interaction and still don't appreciate why this is happening.  It seems counter-intuitive from the purpose of `Refresh`.

Comment: @Edmund Documentation about `Refresh` sucks. Or it's me. In addition, there are multiple cases when Dynamic is not as smart as you'd expect, sometimes it is smarter. The net result is, it's lottery, I hate it :P, I'm not using it almost at all: [related topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78580/5478).

Comment: @Edmund p.s. but this case is quite clear. Also change `amp` range to `1-2` not `0-1` when it's `0` it may trick you that `Dynamic[a]` doesn't matter while it really does.