# How to change random values in manipulate?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, random, output, numerical-value

I made a Manipulate box that is working very well, using lots of random numbers.  I would like to add a button to "reset" (i.e. to change, randomize, or reselect) *all the random parameters*.

Here's the code I added to the Manipulate box, but it doesn't work :

```
Row[{Spacer[200],
    Button[
        "Randomize all parameters",
        Clear["alpha", "Phase", "Amplitude", "Frequency"],
        Appearance -> "Palette",
        ImageSize -> {150, 28}
    ]
}],
```

What should I use instead of `Clear["alpha", "Phase", "Amplitude", "Frequency"]` to ***randomize*** all these parameters, according to their definitions ?

**EDIT :** Here's a complete MWE showing the problem :

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Amplitude[k_] := Amplitude[k] = RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}]
Frequency[k_] := Frequency[k] = RandomReal[{1, 5}]
Phase[k_] := Phase[k] = RandomReal[{0, 2Pi}]

Manipulate[
    Plot[
        Sum[Amplitude[k]Sin[2Pi Frequency[k]t + Phase[k]],
        {k, 1, Nwaves}
        ],
    {t, 0, 1},
    Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-5, 5}},
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
    ImageSize -> 600
    ],
    {{Nwaves, 1, Style["Number of waves", 10]}, 1, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    Delimiter,
    Row[{
        Button[
            "Reset random parameters",
            {(* Reset command for "Amplitude", "Frequency", "Phase" *)},
            Appearance -> "Palette",
            ImageSize -> {250, 28}
        ]
    }],
    ControlPlacement -> Bottom
]
```

**EDIT 2 :**  The "duplicate" referenced above doesn't apply to this question, since the answers are specific to that question.  I don't see how to apply them to the question here.

Comment: Maybe you can directly manipulate the `DownValues`. Something like, `DownValues[alpha] = DownValues[alpha][[{-1}]]`, which resets the rules associated with `alpha` to *only* the original definition. Without an idea of what's happening inside the `Manipulate`, that's the best I can say right now.

Comment: Ok then, I'll add a complete MWE to the question in a few minutes.

Comment: Doesn't have to be complete! Just an idea of what it looks like, a minimal example as it where!

Comment: @march, I've edited the question.

Comment: @garej, I've added an edit to my question.  The answers in your "duplicate" are very specific to the question, and I don't see how to apply them to my problem.  I believe my question is much more general.

Comment: @garej. There's also [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19536/how-to-clear-parts-of-a-memoized-function) about clearing *some* of the `DownValues` of a function (i.e. clear some parts of a memo-ized function), and perhaps a combination of those two posts would compose a duplicate. However, since *two* posts would be required, perhaps it's not a dupe. Nonetheless, those are two good posts to reference.

Comment: @march, I've found a nice (?) solution, but I need comments/suggestions, in case there may be some troubles I don't see,

Comment: @Cham, some troubles may arise when you'll need to put everything within `Manipulate`.

Comment: @garej, what do you mean ?  Could you be more precise ?

Comment: @march, Cham, I don't insist, of course. I'm personally fine with duplicates     when my questions marked as duplicates (often :))) but if it's a problem, I may delete the comment.

Comment: @Cham, I've noticed that you sometimes make a lot of controls. I had problems like [that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89401/random-variable-within-manipulate-how-to-make-it-independent-on-other-controls).

Comment: @garej, yes, most of my Manipulate boxes are using many sliders and buttons.  I always start my codes with a `Clear` everything command, and introduce my functions *before* the `Manipulate` code.  I don't know if this a good practice (probably not !).  If I open several Manipulate projects, I can use just one at a time and need to recompile the code to use another one.  So I guess my habits aren't very good.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way, by directly manipulating the `DownValues` of the variables:

```
resetDVs[var_Symbol] := (DownValues[var] = List@Last@DownValues[var])
```

Then, in the place where

```
{(* Reset command for "Amplitude", "Frequency", "Phase" *)}
```

appears in your code, put

```
{resetDVs /@ {Phase, Amplitude, Frequency}}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the *definitions* of these functions will necessarily be the last element of the list of `DownValues`. This breaks if you have definitions elsewhere, but since you are `Clear`ing first, this should be fine.

Comment: Hmm, it isn't clear.  My button do nothing.  Could you post a modified version of the MWE code I've added to my question ?

Comment: Did you include `resetDVs` after `Clear["Global`*"]`?

Comment: I've added your first line above (`resetDVs[var_Symbol]`) after the Clear all, yes.  Also, take note that I do have other definitions in my whole code, but not random variables.

Comment: I'll post a simplified working version.

Comment: Also, hitting the button doesn't change the image immediately, you have to move the scroll-bar in order to see a difference. It's easiest to see by going to the `NWaves == 1`, hitting the rest button, and then scrolling away and back to `NWaves == 1`.

Comment: Ah ! Yes, it seems to work now.  Thanks in adding this comment !

Comment: There might very well be better (more robust, less likely to cause issues) solutions to this problem. I will continue to think on it, but wait for more solutions, for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I may have found a simple solution, but it asks that I change a big chunk of my whole code.  In the case of the MWE above, it's very simple :

Just add a new random parameter to the random functions :

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Phase[k_, r_] := Phase[k, r] = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]
Amplitude[k_, r_] := Amplitude[k, r] = RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}]
Frequency[k_, r_] := Frequency[k, r] = RandomReal[{1, 5}]
r = 1;

Manipulate[
    Plot[
        Sum[Amplitude[k, r]Sin[2Pi Frequency[k, r]t + Phase[k, r]], {k, 1, Nwaves}],
    {t, 0, 1},
    Frame -> True,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-5, 5}},
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
    ImageSize -> 600
    ],
    {{Nwaves, 1, Style["Number of waves", 10]}, 1, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    Delimiter,
    Row[{
        Button[
            "Reset random parameters",
            {r = RandomReal[]},
            Appearance -> "Palette",
            ImageSize -> {250, 28}
        ]
    }],
    ControlPlacement -> Bottom
]
```

The effect is immediate on the picture.

Is there a better/simpler way of doing this ?  Is this trick robust, or are there any drawback that I don't see yet ?

Comment: This is clever, and I doubt that you'll ever get overlapping `r`'s. However, depending on how many times you reset, the `DownValues` to the function are going to proliferate. I imagine it would take a *lot* of resets to actually start filling up memory, but it's at least something to keep in mind.

Comment: Wow !  Manipulate is so powerfull to visualize things !  It's incredible !  :-)  The Randomize button is now giving some very nice outputs !  I couldn't resist to post a picture of my project : http://s17.postimg.org/qjbpsg21r/manipulate.jpg

Answer (score 1):

As you are using memoization you can `Map` `Unset` over the saved states.  `Quiet` is also used as depending on how far the slider has been moved along (up and back) then not all 20 saved states may be present.

You can add

```
Function[{f}, Quiet@Unset[f[#]] & /@ Range[20]] /@ {Amplitude, Frequency, Phase}
```

as your `(*Reset command for "Amplitude","Frequency","Phase"*)` in `Button`.

This updates immediately on click and does not require redefining your functions (i.e. adding additional parameters).

Hope this helps.